# sysbench Fileio Test FATAL: Failed to write file! errno = 28 (No space left on device)

Tags: prepared-statement, embedded-linux, benchmarking, errno, sysbench

I'm having a problem with sysbench. It worked fine with 3 other platform.
I have an imx8 with 4GB of RAM

do

> sysbench fileio --file-total-size=16G prepare
>
> ## Set Directory Genric/Specific and platform
>
> sysbench fileio --file-total-size=16G --file-test-mode=rndwr --time=900  --file-block-size=3K --file-num=10 --threads=$SysbenchIO --file-fsync-all run > /home/debian/My_Test_Results/imx8m/Witness_Case/Stress-Off/Sysbench/FileIO_Ergebnisse/Fileio_$SysbenchIO
> sleep 10
> sysbench fileio --file-total-size=16G cleanup
> done
> sysbench 1.0.17 (using bundled LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta2)

128 files, 131072Kb each, 16384Mb total
Creating files for the test...
Extra file open flags: (none)
Creating file test_file.0
Creating file test_file.1
Creating file test_file.2
Creating file test_file.3
Creating file test_file.4
Creating file test_file.5
Creating file test_file.6
Creating file test_file.7
Creating file test_file.8
Creating file test_file.9
Creating file test_file.10
Creating file test_file.11
Creating file test_file.12
Creating file test_file.13
Creating file test_file.14
Creating file test_file.15
Creating file test_file.16
Creating file test_file.17
Creating file test_file.18
Creating file test_file.19
Creating file test_file.20
Creating file test_file.21
Creating file test_file.22
Creating file test_file.23
Creating file test_file.24
Creating file test_file.25
Creating file test_file.26
Creating file test_file.27
Creating file test_file.28
Creating file test_file.29
Creating file test_file.30
Creating file test_file.31
Creating file test_file.32
Creating file test_file.33
Creating file test_file.34
Creating file test_file.35
Creating file test_file.36
Creating file test_file.37
Creating file test_file.38
Creating file test_file.39
Creating file test_file.40
Creating file test_file.41
Creating file test_file.42
Creating file test_file.43
Creating file test_file.44
Creating file test_file.45
Creating file test_file.46
Creating file test_file.47
Creating file test_file.48
FATAL: Failed to write file! errno = 28 (No space left on device)
sysbench 1.0.17 (using bundled LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta2)

I don't know how to deal with this. I did a df -i and df -h but still i don't see anyproblem
[df -h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hkahb.png)
[df -i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvlPb.png)

CPU and Threads Tests worked fine but not the fileio test

Comment: Are you sure that you have at least 16GiB of free disk space to conduct this test? Also mind that some space is reserved for root

Comment: @Ctx how do I know how much free space do I have please ?

Comment: Your df output shows, that you only have 6.1GB of free space, you should lower the value in your sysbench command from 16GB to 4GB

Comment: oh what a dummy I am  !!  Thank you for your response I appreciate it :D